can't find the page URL
I got the same error while writing code.

I started making this project using a video tutorial on YouTube. I think the problem is in the URLConf but I can’t find this problem myself.
Essentially the problem is that when I go to the site and press a certain button, this error appears and does not find this page, why?
In my urls.py there may be a mistake that's for sure.
from django.urls import path
from . import views



urlpatterns = [


    path('login/', views.loginPage, name="login"),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name="logout"),
    path('register/', views.registerPage, name="register"),


    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('room/<str:pk>/', views.room, name="room"),
    path('profile/<str:pk>',views.userProfile,name="user-profile"),


    path('create-room/', views.createRoom, name="create-room"),
    path('update-room/<str:pk>/', views.updateRoom, name="update-room"),
    path('delete-room/<str:pk>/', views.deleteRoom, name="delete-room"),
    path('delete-message/<str:pk>/', views.deleteMessage, name="delete-message"),

]

my views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from .models import Room, Topic, Message
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .forms import RoomForm



#rooms = [
  #  {'id': 1, 'name': 'Lets learn python!' },
  #  {'id': 2, 'name': 'Design with me' },
 #   {'id': 3, 'name': 'Frontend developers' },
#]


def loginPage(request):

    page = 'login'
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')


    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username').lower()
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except:
            messages.error(request,'User does not exist')

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Username OR password does not exit')


    context = {'page': page}
    return render(request, 'base/login_register.html', context)

def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')


def registerPage(request):

    form = UserCreationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.username = user.username.lower()
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'An error occurred during registration')


    return render(request, 'base/login_register.html',{'form':form})


def home(request):
    q=request.GET.get('q') if request.GET.get('q')!= None else ''

    rooms = Room.objects.filter(
        Q(topic__name__icontains=q) |
        Q(name__icontains=q) |
        Q(description__icontains=q)
    )

    topics = Topic.objects.all()
    room_count = rooms.count()
    room_messages = Message.objects.all()


    context = {'rooms': rooms, 'topics' : topics,
               'room_count' : room_count,'room_messages': room_messages}

    return render(request, 'base/home.html', context)

def room(request,pk):

    room = Room.objects.get(id=pk)
    room_messages = room.message_set.all()
    participants = room.participants.all(
    )
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = Message.objects.create(
            user = request.user,
            room=room,
            body=request.POST.get('body')
        )
        room.participants.add(request.user)
        return redirect('room',pk=room.id)

    context = {'room': room,'room_messages':room_messages,
               'participants': participants}
    return render(request, 'base/room.html', context)




def userProfile(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    context={'user':user}
    return render(request,'base/room.html',context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
def createRoom(requset):
    form = RoomForm
    if requset.method == 'POST':
        form = RoomForm(requset.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(requset, 'base/room_form.html',context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
def updateRoom(request,pk):
    room = Room.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = RoomForm(instance=room)

    if request.user != room.host:
        return HttpResponse('Your are not allowed here!!!')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RoomForm(request.POST, instance=room)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request,'base/room_form.html', context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
def deleteRoom(request, pk):
    room = Room.objects.get(id=pk)

    if request.user != room.host:
        return HttpResponse('Your are not allowed here!!!')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        room.delete()
        return redirect('home')
    return render(request,'base/delete.html',{'obj': room})


@login_required(login_url='login')
def deleteMessage(request, pk):
    message = Room.objects.get(id=pk)

    if request.user != message.host:
        return HttpResponse('Your are not allowed here!!!')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        message.delete()
        return redirect('home')
    return render(request,'base/delete.html',{'obj': message})

If this information is not enough to solve this error, I can provide my other files with code.

Provide the html from where you are hitting the URL

Typo: At least according to the image your template tag looks like {% url 'delete-message' message.id% } That's wrong because you have a space between the % and }. Rewrite that as {% url 'delete-message' message.id %} and it should work as long as that message object is present in your context.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I had this in mind too but I couldn’t find a canonical reference. If you can, write an answer.

@ChukwujiobiCanon I am not posting an answer since I've voted to close this as a typo, an extra space between the % and the } is very much not the expected syntax and can be considered a typo. Also other than that this question actually lacks a [mre] since they haven't actually shared that code as text anywhere.

The problem is that you passed this:
{% url 'delete-message' message.id% }

Where as it should be this:
{% url 'delete-message' message.id %}

Notice the last % sign how it is placed.

thanks for the answer, you were right, the mistake was that I put extra spaces %

Url name of your delete message view is 'delete-message'. You need to pass the id as well so django knows which one to delete.
{% url 'delete-message' message.id %}"

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls

That's not going to work since you can't (and don't need to) use the {{ }} syntax inside template tags ({% tag ... %})

You are right. However, removing brackets should work. I updated the answer.
